# Can I connect just the onClick function to the Redux store, instead of connecting the button component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using **react-redux** to connect the data in my **Redux** store.  I have discovered how to connect with selectors (as `mapStateToProps`) so data is available as props in React components when I need it.

I have a React button component, and I have made props available to it. From other answers I think I can see how to specify an **onClick** function so the eventHandler has access to those props.

However I realise that the button itself does not need those props, and it is just the **onClick** event that needs them. Is there a way to connect the **onClick** function to the Redux store instead of connecting the button component?

I have tried a few ways, but I am getting a bit lost between **classes, functions, HOCs, composition etc.**

### Update

A bit more context: In any user session the state I am interested in (geography) for this onClick function is picked up initially from a database, and then hardly ever changed. The onClick action I am wanting to achieve is something based on this geography data. If the geography data does change then almost everything in the DOM will need rerendering.

---

Thanks for your comments - I have explored more, and managed to create a skeleton app in codesandbox called [TestOnClick](https://codesandbox.io/embed/74kvlp1mzx). I think it may be one answer to my question.

In the app there are two buttons

- one gets data from the store as props, and invests the onClick function with them as @lecstor showed me - I suppose this is fairly standard stuff but I am new to React
- the other has no such props but calls an onClick function that itself uses getState() to to get the same data from the store

Both seem to be able to be expanded to do what I want, as they have all they need to do it. IF so I plan to use the second button approach, where the button itself does not have the props.

As I understand it, the use of getState rather than connect means that Redux does not notify my function to be re-rendered if the data in the store changes. But I don't see that as an issue because as an onClick function there is nothing that needs rendering, and in any case almost the whole DOM will need to be rerendered anyway. Have I understood this correctly?

**Update 2**
I am trying to use the Without Props button approach in my real project and facing circular dependencies, so maybe it is not a valid answer. Further exploration to come.

Comment: Could you share your code? Maybe on codesandbox.io or maybe there's a github repo that the community can refer to?
It's very basic to pass props and call the onClick function and pass the props as arguments to it, but not sure what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: @SivcanSingh I would agree on sharing the code, but you can do it easily enough in here as well, I had created a year ago a [default playground on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182633/react-redux-default-playground) that I use quite often when I have to implement a react/redux snippet as part of an answer ;)

Comment: @Icepickle That's some good work. Will test it out. Whereas the OP can move the code in there and let the others help him out easily.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I could not understand what to do with the default playgound, so I will have a go at putting the relevant part of my app into codesandbox.

Comment: Well you should always add the relevant code inside your question itself. You can use the stacksnippets here to have a runable version of a [mcve] (so you shouldn't provide all of it, just the part were you are stuck at and what can be easily reproduced for us to answer your question)

Comment: @PeterCooper There is absolutely no need for you to pass the `remaining` props to the button, why ever would you like to do that, the button doesn't have any benefit from those properties ;) Neither would be there a need to have the event handled in your `WithPropsButton`, as your maincontainer could pass along the "required" properties (title for example, maybe opcode) and the rest can be handled through passing the appropriate events

Comment: I see that with the simple example, however I was exploring how to do it for elements well down the tree, so I do not have to pass props down through too many layers. Thanks for helping me learn. I am happy to leave it there.

Comment: I don't get it exactly, as you already connect your `WithPropsButton`, so you obviously know, that you can connect simple components as well

Comment: What I wanted to do was connect just the onClick function itself without connecting the button component - as I think I have managed to do with the Without Props button. (I have added a further update above)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the button purely to call a function in your component which reads data/functions from props or state.

```
class Form extends Component {
  state = { name: "Fred" };

  onClick = () => {
    const { name } = this.state;
    const { userId, saveUser } = this.props;
    saveUser({ userId, name });
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.onClick}>Save Me</button>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. However what I am ideally looking for is if I can leave the button without any props and connect the onClick function itself to pick props up from the store.

Comment: @PeterCooper How would your `onClick` function then know how to handle a click? Somewhere you have to meet the event with a handler that gets the correct data. The code here is the solution that will be handled the easiest as the button only gets the appropriate handler added. The only nitpick is that we don't even have the code of the OP, so it is hard to provide an answer for it based on speculation

Comment: @PeterCooper, at this point I have to ask, what is it you are trying to achieve? You need to get the "click" from the dom to your component code, there's not much getting around that. The only alternative would be to wrap your button with another element which does the same as we've done here, but acts on the event when it bubble up.

Comment: I've added an update to my original post that gives a little more context, and some further explorations.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong: You want to pass the minimum props required to your `Button` component. Ideally only the single function which would have access to `state.geography.place`, but not the state.

That is possible if you make use of [advanced connect options](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  opsdetails: placeSelector(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  alertPlace(opsdetails) {
    console.log(opsdetails);
    alert(
      `Place via WithPropsButton is ${opsdetails.OPSCode}) ${
        opsdetails.OPSName
      }`
    );
    //dispatch(YOUR_ACTION)
  }
});

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => ({
  ...ownProps,
  alertPlace: () => dispatchProps.alertPlace(stateProps.opsdetails)
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  mergeProps
)(WithPropsButton);
```

`WithPropsButton` gets props returned from `mergeProps` function, that is any own props passed directly to it and `alertPlace` function.

Which also allows to simplify the component and make it a stateless function:

```js
const WithPropsButton = ({ alertPlace, ...remaining }) => (
  <button onClick={alertPlace} {...remaining}>
    With Props
  </button>
);
```

One thing to keep in mind:

`alertPlace` function prop will be recreated each time `state.geography.place` changes, so if the connected stateful component was something complex you would like to avoid re-rendering too often (not in this case with a simple button) further changes are needed.

To avoid re-rendering you could implement a `shouldComponentUpdate` that would ignore `alertPlace` prop updates.

I forked your codesandbox and implemented what I'm talking about here.
Please see https://codesandbox.io/s/pk60228qk0

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to map any Props, you can use null as the first argument to the connect function:

```js
MyConnectedComponent = connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent)
```

Comment: While this snippet may answer the question,  snippet without any explanations are considered as low quality post, please review this.